# Borda chanfrada transparenet apenas com css

Tags: css, css3

Existe uma forma simples de fazer uma borda chanfrada apenas com CSS, mas transparente. Sem precisar de um svg, png, etc?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o que já fiz até agora: https://jsfiddle.net/Cafardo/zn5oysqy/5/

```css
.home_fundo{
   width: 300px;
   height: auto;
   background: url(http://www.simi.org.br/files/Janeiro%20-%202017/11096.jpg);
}
.home_banner_caixa {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #c77316;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.home_banner_caixa_chanfro {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.home_banner_caixa_chanfro1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.home_banner_caixa_chanfro2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 35px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #c77316;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_fundo">
  <div class="home_banner_caixa">
    <div class="home_banner_caixa_chanfro">
      <div class="home_banner_caixa_chanfro1"></div>
      <div class="home_banner_caixa_chanfro2"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>
      Lorem ipsum
      <br> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vitae augue ut mi fermentum sodales. Sed euismod est mollis sem malesuada, vitae placerat est congue
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reparem que o canto banco deveria ser transparente, pensei que talvez exista algum tipo de mascara em jquery para deixar a div branca do chanfrado transparente, ou algo do tipo...  conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Elementos com cantos cortados com Css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52938/elementos-com-cantos-cortados-com-css)

Comment: Vc também pode fazer usando pseudo elemento. Vou responder na outra pergunta com essa opção caso tenha interesse. []´s

Comment: Obrigado, o post me ajudou bastante. O problema é que precisaria ser transparente a bordinha chanfrada, e não com uma cor....

Comment: De uma olhada na propriedade `clip-path` em [MDN clip-path CSS Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). *Observe a tabela de compatibilidade de navegadores.

Comment: Obrigado! Mas funciona em poucos navegadores....

Comment: Não vai ficar bonito, mas vou fazer um exemplo pra vc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Para Imagens**

No caso de precisar cortar o canto de uma imagem com CSS, ou chanfrar uma imagem com CSS você pode consultar aqui: [Fazer efeitos nas bordas em CSS, como chanfro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355578/fazer-efeitos-nas-bordas-em-css-como-chanfro)

---

**Para core sólidas**

Existem alguma opções diferentes, vou abordar 3 delas.

**Opção 1**

Opção mais atual com com `linear-gradiente`. A técnica é fazer um `linear-gradiente` em `45deg`, onde a última porção referente a 10% do gradiente é transparente. Assim teremos **uma cor sólida de 0% até 90%** e **de 90% a 100% a cor transparente**.

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, blue, green);
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f00 0%, #f00 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 90%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Fiz essa opção usando pseudo elementos `::before` e `::after` mais `transform: skewX(45deg);` assim o canto da `div` fica "transparente" diferente das outras opções da resposta marcada como Duplicada...

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/420/320);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    background-color: tomato;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    top: -20px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}
.container::before {
    content: "";
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -20px;
    height: calc(100% + 20px);
    width: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Meu texto aqui! Meu texto aqui! Meu texto aqui!</div>
```

---

### Edit

**Opção 100% Crossbrowser:** *(o código é mais feio, mas funciona em todos os browsers)*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/460/320);
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    background-color: limegreen;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.barra {
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -20px;
    background-color: limegreen;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -20px;
    border-left: 10px solid limegreen;
    border-bottom: 10px solid limegreen;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="barra"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    Meu texto aqui! Meu texto aqui! Meu texto aqui!
</div>
```

**Dica:** Nessa técnica usei `bordas` com cores transparentes e `position:absolut` com `top negativo`

Comment: Perfeito! O segundo exemplo fucnionou muito bem. Tive que fazer algumas mudanças no layout.. pois o texto começa a ser escrito no meio do chanfrado na versão original, mas tudo bem. obrigado!

Comment: De uma olhada nessa resposta no StackOverflow gringo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138218/border-bevelled-transparent-only-with-css

Comment: Caio o CSS é lindo né! Com linear-gradiente foi algo que não me passou pela cabeça! Muito interessante também!

Comment: Ótima resposta @hugocsl, +1!

Comment: @AndréFilipe valeu jovem! Ela é criativa, mas não funciona para imagem... pois é uma composição de pseudo elementos etc... aqui deixei uma alternativa para usar com imagens https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355578/fazer-efeitos-nas-bordas-em-css-como-chanfro/355584#355584

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, bacana. vou dar uma olhada meu amigo!