# Fazer efeitos nas bordas em CSS, como chanfro

Tags: php, css, css3, wordpress

Preciso fazer uns efeitos nas bordas de imagens e retângulos, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que são nos cantos, no retângulo cinza esta no topo direito, nas imagens na base esquerda.

Consegui fazer, mas apenas como borde-radius usando esse código:

```
 border: 10px solid #cb3527; 
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #cb3527;
```

Ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, preciso que fique como na primeira imagem, acho que é efeito chanfro!

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280711/borda-chanfrada-transparenet-apenas-com-css/281048#281048

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pra cores sólidas**

No caso de cores sólidas para cortar a borda com CSS, ou chanfrar um canto com CSS você pode consultar aqui: [Borda chanfrada transparenet apenas com css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280711/borda-chanfrada-transparenet-apenas-com-css/281048#281048)

---

**Pra imagens**

Sugiro essa técnica. Vc pode fazer uma máscara na imagem usando `-webkit-mask-image` o suporte é relativamente bom, deixando apenas o IE de fora como vc pode consultar aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks

A ideia é que se tem um gradiente com as cores preto e transparente, tudo que está abaixo da cor preta vai aparecer, então deixei o gradiente em `-135deg` *(para ficar no canto inferior esquerdo obs. do @WictorChaves)* assim ele vai ser o angulo do "chanfro" e tendo 90% da área em preto, logo o triangulo "cortado" no canto representa 10% do tamanho total, isso pode te ajudar a ajusta o tamanho do chanfro como quiser. Ali vc tb pode usar medidas em `px` caso queira

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
margin:0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(red 0, blue 120px);
}
img {
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-135deg, #000000 90%, transparent 90%);

}
```

```html
<img src="https://placecage.com/200/100" alt="">
```

Comment: Coloque 135 no lugar dos 45 para que a borda fique do lado debaixo :)

Comment: @WictorChaves opa! Verdade rss!!

Comment: Obrigado irmão, abração